# Node ACL module throws undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, acl

I am trying to use acl module in node.I am using the mongodb backend for the same, but it does not gets initialised and thorws error saying undefined is not a function.

My app.js is something like

```
var acl = require('acl');



var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function () {
console.error('database connection error:');
process.exit(1);
});
db.once('open', function (callback) {
// debugger;
var  acl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend("mongodb://localhost/myapp", "accesscontrol_"));


});

//initialising the acl
acl.allow([
{
    roles:['admin'],
    allows:[
        {resources:['vieworder','editorder'], permissions:['*']}
    ]
},
{
    roles:['driver','executive'],
    allows:[
        {resources:['vieworder'], permissions:['view']}
    ]
},
{
    roles:['executive'],
    allows:[
        {resources:['editorder'], permissions:['view','edit']}
    ]
}
]);
```

It fails in the run pointing at acl.allow as undefined is not a function.so i am assuming it says that for the variable "acl".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are assigning your instance variable to the same name as the libary require. Use a different name for the instance.

Comment: @BlakesSeven yes, rookie mistake. that did it. Thank you very much ,but still its logging in a lot of stuff in console sayiing unhandled rejection error.

Comment: That's called a different question here. [Ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that error. Or better yet do some searching/reading for the possible cause.

Comment: acl returns an object with the settings, but allow is not in its functions. I have the same problem.